# How to filter an object list on multiple arrays in react.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I need to filter an array of items using multiple filter arrays. Output should display only the ones that match all of the selected filters.

for example:
Main array contains list of a table

```
 ID   TypeID   LocationID    Name
 1     2          16          AB
 2     2          22          EF
 3     4          75          PQ
 4     4          40          MN
 5     3          16          AB
```

And I have three filter arrays:

```
 TypeFilter = [2, 3]
 LocationFilter = [22, 16] 
 NameFilter = ["AB","MN"]
```

After applying these filters, output should be an object list of this table:

```
 ID   TypeID   LocationID    Name
 1     2          16          AB
 5     3          16          AB
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably you need to do chaining of `filter` function for every condition

Comment: just do an inclusive filter in one pass. no need to chain filters here. `arr.filter( item => TypeFilter.includes(item.TypeId) && LocationFilter.includes(item.LocationId) && NameFilter.includes(item.Name) )`.. However it would be more efficient to store the filters as objects, this way you dont need to do an includes but rather an `O(1)` lookup on the object key.

Comment: It worked. Just one more question, How to ignore a particular filter if its length is 0. for eg: if LocationFilter is empty and I want to exclude it from the the result query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter each `key` by it's correspondent filter:

```
const result = items.filter(item =>{
    const {TypeId, LocationId, Name} = item
    return TypeFilter.includes(TypeId) && LocationFilter.includes(LocationId) && NameFilter.includes(Name)
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more question, How to ignore a particular filter if its length is 0. for eg: if LocationFilter is empty and I want to exclude it from the the  result query.

Comment: Could be something like this: `TypeFilter.includes(TypeId) && (!LocationFilter || LocationFilter.includes(LocationId))`